Regarding shudhi of semem
Sometimes after sex with my wife when my semen is in the hand I touch phone , door knobs etc and after bath when I try to maintain madi I doubt phone , door knobs etc having small smears of semen and I don't understand how to use them and keep madi.does semen disturb the madi?

You are supposed to take a shower and wash your hands after sex.

Anything which comes out of the genitals like stool, urine, semen etc is considered unclean. Except that which comes from the genitals of Cows. Infact simply touching the genitals is considered unclean and you should wash your hands, and if you are a priest/pujari you should take a bath.
As per the smritis, having sex is an unclean practice and you are not allowed in the temple or near yajnas if you had sex and have not taken proper bathing and cleaning procedures.
So, to keep your madi:

don't take your phone in your washroom, toilet etc
don't touch it after sex, or with semen on your hands
if you can't follow the above, clean your Phone with a cleaning solution and then you can touch it again after bath.

